# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_node' of undefined

Tags: javascript, famous-engine

Please see source code posted here

https://github.com/codesdk/famous_engine_issue_debug_position

Follow the steps in README.md

I am getting the following error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_node' of undefined

which traces to the following line

```
 */
function Position(node) {
    this._node = node;  <----------------------
```

Please help.

Comment: Hmm, `this` is undefined. Maybe `this` is being unset somewhere?

Comment: It’s very likely you’re forgetting to use `new` on a `Position(…)` somewhere. Here, for example: https://github.com/codesdk/famous_engine_issue_debug_position/blob/1ce09837a0ae0021e50bc0831b8a77a827b9509f/src/MyScene.js#L24 Next time, please read the stack trace and include the relevant parts of your code in your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Right here: https://github.com/codesdk/famous_engine_issue_debug_position/blob/master/src/MyScene.js#L24

You forgot the `new` keyword.